# 60% RAM usage with very little running

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory

I run Windows 10 and since a few days my memory usage has been around 60% all the time. I am pretty much a layman but can you help by looking at these print screens?

Processes:

> [image: Processes]

Memory:

> [image: Memory]

RAMMap:

> [image: RAMMap]

Comment: This all feels like an [XY problem question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Is there are problem? Or are you just noticing memory usage and are assuming this is a problem?

Comment: 4 to 5GB base memory use on Windows 10 is fairly normal. It is simply a more demanding system than previous.

Comment: So even with just the background processes running 50+ % is normal? I just noticed when BlueStacks said "there might be not enough memory". Mapped file memory also of no concern?

Comment: The bulk of "mapped file" memory is just memory-backed cache for files that can be released instantly. The OS must read files into memory for programs to access, and so it just kind of holds them in case you need them again as this is very much faster than re-accessing SSD/HDD  (I once wrote a very simple read-and-forget program to examine file throughput on a network and the first read of a large file might be 18 seconds, but reading the same file a second time was <.5 second due to OS memory mapping). In your screencap, the "active" memory mapped number is *not* instantly releasable (?)

Comment: "So even with just the background processes running 50+ % is normal"   <-- depending on activity, yes - normal. I am not familiar with Blue Stacks, but if that needs memory, you might (as I posted) consider upgrading to 16 GB.  8 GB is pretty much the minimum today.

Comment: Memory messages from programs are messages about program faults, not about Windows or installed memory. The program tried to use memory in an invalid way - eg it tried to use an uninitialised  variable (which will have a memory address of 0) and 0-64k is always an invalid address on Windows to catch programs using unitialised (or freed) variables. It may be the program will infinitely recurse because of a logical error and it will eventually run out of stack space.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your Windows 10 machine is 64-bit (most are) and in any 64-bit machine, 4 GB or a bit more as base memory usage is entirely normal.

This has been true for my 64-bit Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 10 machines and customer machines as well.

You do not have anything to be concerned about. Also, because it is entirely normal, I do not think it warrants any special analysis or attention.

I am not familiar with Blue Stacks, but try starting with out Blue Stacks and also with just normal (say) Office Programs. It should still come out to 4GB plus or minus.

Remember that memory is to be used. Nothing is saved by removing apps that use memory. So long as your total memory (looks like 8 GB) satisfies your needs, again, nothing to worry about.

If you can, you might consider upgrading to 16 GB when / if there is a need.